# Filter on Null for lookup column in SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest

I need do a filter where a lookup column is null, doesn't point to any thing. I tried

```
var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl   
+ "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/"
+ "items?$select=ID,Title,Name,Company/Id" 
+ "," + appDict.fieldDict["WorkPhone"]
+ "," + appDict.fieldDict["Email"]
+ "," + appDict.fieldDict["MobilePhone"]
+ "&$expand=Company/Id"
+ "&$filter=Company/Id eq null"
+ "&$orderby=Name asc"
```

but it doesn't work, I get no results even when there is a list item that has null as the lookup.

Comment: Please elaborate more, Your question is not clear enough to understand.

Comment: Did you create `Id` column in `Company` list? or it is the default one?

Comment: `Id` is the default one in the `Company` list.